# javascript (embedded in HTML) document.createElement("canvas") not showing in browser

Tags: javascript

I have javascript code embedded in a simple HTML file, that doesn't contain any other script, apart from this javascript code.  I'm using `document.createElement("canvas")` in order to display a neural network prediction model, but yet nothing shows up on the page when I load the HTML doc in the browser (just an empty white page). I'm a beginner to JS, so I wouldn't be surprised if it's something silly that I overlooked. Apologies in advance for the big portion of code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Training red/blue flower prediction model neural network (using JS)
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            //training set. [Input data(length, width), output data(color(0=blue and 1=red))]
            var dataB1 = [2, 1, 0];
            var dataB2 = [3, 1, 0];
            var dataB3 = [2, 0.5, 0];
            var dataB4 = [1, 1, 0];

            var dataR1 = [3, 1.5, 1];
            var dataR2 = [3.5, 0.5, 1];
            var dataR3 = [4, 1.5, 1];
            var dataR4 = [5.5, 1, 1];

            //unknown type (data we want to find)
            var dataU = [4.5, 1, "it should be 1"];

            var all_points = [dataB1, dataB2, dataB3, dataB4, dataR1, dataR2, dataR3, dataR4];

            function sigmoid(x) {
                return 1/(1+Math.exp(-x));
            }

            //training
            function train() {
                let w1 = Maths.random()*0.2-0.1;
                let w2 = Maths.random()*0.2-0.1;
                let b = Maths.random()*0.2-0.1;
                let learning_rate = 0.2; // fraction of the weight that we're going to be using 
                for (let iter = 0; iter < 50000; iter++) {
                    // pick a random point
                    let random_idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * all_points.length);
                    let point = all_point[random_idx];
                    let target = point[2]; //target stored in 3rd coord of points

                    // feed forward
                    let z = w1 * point[0] + w2 * point[1] + b;
                    let pred = sigmoid(z);

                    // now we compare the model prediction with the target
                    let cost = (pred - target) ** 2;

                    // now we find the slope of the cost w.r.t. each parameter (w1, w2, b)
                    // bring derivative through square function
                    let dcost_dpred = 2 * (pred - target);

                    // bring derivative through sigmoid
                    // derivative of sigmoid can be written using more sigmoids! d/dz sigmoid(z) = sigmoid(z)*(1-sigmoid(z))
                    let dpred_dz = sigmoid(z) * (1-sigmoid(z));

                    // I think you forgot these in your slope calculations?
                    let dz_dw1 = point[0];
                    let dz_dw2 = point[1];
                    let dz_db = 1;

                    // now we can get the partial derivatives using the chain rule
                    // notice the pattern? We're bringing how the cost changes through each function, first through the square, then through the sigmoid
                    // and finally whatever is multiplying our parameter of interest becomes the last part
                    let dcost_dw1 = dcost_pred * dpred_dz * dz_dw1; 
                    let dcost_dw2 = dcost_dpred * dpred_dz * dz_dw2;
                    let dcost_b = dcost_dpred * dpred_dz * dz_db;

                    // now we update our parameters!
                    w1 -= learning_rate * dcost_dw1;
                    w2 -= learning_rate * dcost_dw2;
                    b -= learning_rate * dcost_b;
                }

                // return the learnt parameters, assuming after 50000 loops of error corrections the network has reached its minima point of error.
                return {w1: w1, w2: w2, b: b};
            }

            let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvas.width = 400;
            canvas.height = 400;
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.font = "Helvetica";

            // map points from graph coordinates to the screen
            let graph_size = {width: 7, height: 7};
            function to_screen(x, y) {
                return {x: (x/graph_size.width)*canvas.width, y: -(y/graph_size.height)*canvas.height + canvas.height};
            }

            // map points from screen coordinates to the graph
            function to_graph(x, y) {
                return {x: x/canvas.width*graph_size.width, y: graph_size.height - y/canvas.height*graph_size.height};
            }

            // draw the graph's grid lines
            function draw_grid() {
                ctx.strokeStyle = "#AAAAAA";
                for (let j = 0; j <= graph_size.width; j++) {

                    // x lines
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    let p = to_screen(j, 0);
                    ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
                    p = to_screen(j, graph_size.height); 
                    ctx.lineTo(p.x, p.y);
                    ctx.stroke();

                    // y lines
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    let p = to_screen(0, j);
                    ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
                    p = to_screen(graph_size.width, j); 
                    ctx.lineTo(p.x, p.y);
                    ctx.stroke();
                }
            }

            // draw points
            function draw_points() {
                // unknown
                let p = to_screen(dataU[0], dataU[1]); 
                ctx.fillStyle = "#555555";
                ctx.fillText("???", p.x-8, p.y-5); 
                ctx.fillRect(p.x-2, p.y-2, 4, 4);

                // draw points
                ctx.fillStyle = "#0000FF";
                for (let j = 0; j < all_points.length; j++) {
                    let point = all_points[j];
                    if (point[2] == 0) {
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#0000FF";
                    } else {
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
                    }
                    p = to_screen(point[0], point[1]);
                    ctx.fillRect(p.x-2, p.y-2, 4, 4);
                }
            }

            //visualize model output on grid of points
            function visualize_params(params) {
                ctx.save();
                ctx.globalAlpha = 0.2;
                let step_size = 0.1;
                let box_size = canvas.width/(graph_size.width/step_size);

                for (let xx = 0; xx < graph_size.width; xx += step_size) {
                    for (let yy = 0; yy < graph_size.height; yy += step_size) {
                        let model_out = sigmoid( xx * params.w1 + yy * params.w2 + params.b );
                        if (model_out < 0.5) {
                            // blue
                            ctx.fillStyle = "#0000FF";
                        } else {
                            //red
                            ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000"
                        }
                        let p = to_screen(xx, yy);
                        ctx.fillRect(p.x, p.y, box_size, box_size); 
                    }
                }
                ctx.restore();
            }

            // find parameters
            var params = train();

            // visualize model output
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            draw_grid();
            draw_points();
            visualize_params(params);

            // label what the model would say for a given mouse position
            window.onmousemove = function(evt) {
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 100, 50);

                let p = {x: 10, y: 20};

                let mouse = {x: evt.offsetX, y: evt.offsetY};
                let mouse_graph = to_graph(mouse.x, mouse.y);

                ctx.fillText("x: " + Math.round(mouse_graph.x*100)/100, p.x, p.y);
                ctx.fillText("y: " + Math.round(mouse_graph.y*100)/100, p.x, p.y +10);
                // model output
                let model_out = sigmoid( mouse_graph.x * params.w1 + mouse_graph.y * params.w2 + params.b );
                model_out = Math.round(model_out*100)/100;
                ctx.fillText("prediction: " + model_out, p.x, p.y + 20);
            }        
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Basically I'm expected to see the image below to show up in the browser: 
[image: expected output image on browser!]

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, You are missing the JS & HTML Syntax. Once you have written your <script>....</script> where your JS code resides, you will then need to call this JS script on the HTML body <body>......Make your JS script function call here </body>. Add also any CSS files on your HTML header <head> ..CSS or external JS file</head>. You can add your JS into HTML with <div>.. </div>.

Comment: Thank you for the help @Juniar. I realised there are mistakes I made in the js code. The answer below from Maheer Ali fixed it. Thank you for your help as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the code I provided you were making some simple mistakes nothing more.
`let w1 = Maths.random()*0.2-0.1;` Using `Maths` **Line:33**
`let point = all_point[random_idx];`. `all_point` istead of all_points **Line:40**
`dcost_pred` instead of `dcost_dpred` **Line:66**
using `p` twice in `function draw_grid()`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Training red/blue flower prediction model neural network (using JS)
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            //training set. [Input data(length, width), output data(color(0=blue and 1=red))]
            var dataB1 = [2, 1, 0];
            var dataB2 = [3, 1, 0];
            var dataB3 = [2, 0.5, 0];
            var dataB4 = [1, 1, 0];

            var dataR1 = [3, 1.5, 1];
            var dataR2 = [3.5, 0.5, 1];
            var dataR3 = [4, 1.5, 1];
            var dataR4 = [5.5, 1, 1];

            //unknown type (data we want to find)
            var dataU = [4.5, 1, "it should be 1"];

            var all_points = [dataB1, dataB2, dataB3, dataB4, dataR1, dataR2, dataR3, dataR4];

            function sigmoid(x) {
                return 1/(1+Math.exp(-x));
            }

            //training
            function train() {
                let w1 = Math.random()*0.2-0.1;
                let w2 = Math.random()*0.2-0.1;
                let b = Math.random()*0.2-0.1;
                let learning_rate = 0.2; // fraction of the weight that we're going to be using 
                for (let iter = 0; iter < 50000; iter++) {
                    // pick a random point
                    let random_idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * all_points.length);
                    let point = all_points[random_idx];
                    let target = point[2]; //target stored in 3rd coord of points

                    // feed forward
                    let z = w1 * point[0] + w2 * point[1] + b;
                    let pred = sigmoid(z);

                    // now we compare the model prediction with the target
                    let cost = (pred - target) ** 2;

                    // now we find the slope of the cost w.r.t. each parameter (w1, w2, b)
                    // bring derivative through square function
                    let dcost_dpred = 2 * (pred - target);

                    // bring derivative through sigmoid
                    // derivative of sigmoid can be written using more sigmoids! d/dz sigmoid(z) = sigmoid(z)*(1-sigmoid(z))
                    let dpred_dz = sigmoid(z) * (1-sigmoid(z));

                    // I think you forgot these in your slope calculations?
                    let dz_dw1 = point[0];
                    let dz_dw2 = point[1];
                    let dz_db = 1;

                    // now we can get the partial derivatives using the chain rule
                    // notice the pattern? We're bringing how the cost changes through each function, first through the square, then through the sigmoid
                    // and finally whatever is multiplying our parameter of interest becomes the last part
                    let dcost_dw1 = dcost_dpred * dpred_dz * dz_dw1; 
                    let dcost_dw2 = dcost_dpred * dpred_dz * dz_dw2;
                    let dcost_b = dcost_dpred * dpred_dz * dz_db;

                    // now we update our parameters!
                    w1 -= learning_rate * dcost_dw1;
                    w2 -= learning_rate * dcost_dw2;
                    b -= learning_rate * dcost_b;
                }

                // return the learnt parameters, assuming after 50000 loops of error corrections the network has reached its minima point of error.
                return {w1: w1, w2: w2, b: b};
            }

            let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvas.width = 400;
            canvas.height = 400;
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.font = "Helvetica";

            // map points from graph coordinates to the screen
            let graph_size = {width: 7, height: 7};
            function to_screen(x, y) {
                return {x: (x/graph_size.width)*canvas.width, y: -(y/graph_size.height)*canvas.height + canvas.height};
            }

            // map points from screen coordinates to the graph
            function to_graph(x, y) {
                return {x: x/canvas.width*graph_size.width, y: graph_size.height - y/canvas.height*graph_size.height};
            }

            // draw the graph's grid lines
            function draw_grid() {
                ctx.strokeStyle = "#AAAAAA";
                for (let j = 0; j <= graph_size.width; j++) {

                    // x lines
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    let p = to_screen(j, 0);
                    ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
                    p = to_screen(j, graph_size.height); 
                    ctx.lineTo(p.x, p.y);
                    ctx.stroke();

                    // y lines
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    p = to_screen(0, j);
                    ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
                    p = to_screen(graph_size.width, j); 
                    ctx.lineTo(p.x, p.y);
                    ctx.stroke();
                }
            }

            // draw points
            function draw_points() {
                // unknown
                let p = to_screen(dataU[0], dataU[1]); 
                ctx.fillStyle = "#555555";
                ctx.fillText("???", p.x-8, p.y-5); 
                ctx.fillRect(p.x-2, p.y-2, 4, 4);

                // draw points
                ctx.fillStyle = "#0000FF";
                for (let j = 0; j < all_points.length; j++) {
                    let point = all_points[j];
                    if (point[2] == 0) {
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#0000FF";
                    } else {
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
                    }
                    p = to_screen(point[0], point[1]);
                    ctx.fillRect(p.x-2, p.y-2, 4, 4);
                }
            }
   
            //visualize model output on grid of points
            function visualize_params(params) {
                ctx.save();
                ctx.globalAlpha = 0.2;
                let step_size = 0.1;
                let box_size = canvas.width/(graph_size.width/step_size);

                for (let xx = 0; xx < graph_size.width; xx += step_size) {
                    for (let yy = 0; yy < graph_size.height; yy += step_size) {
                        let model_out = sigmoid( xx * params.w1 + yy * params.w2 + params.b );
                        if (model_out < 0.5) {
                            // blue
                            ctx.fillStyle = "#0000FF";
                        } else {
                            //red
                            ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000"
                        }
                        let p = to_screen(xx, yy);
                        ctx.fillRect(p.x, p.y, box_size, box_size); 
                    }
                }
                ctx.restore();
            }

            // find parameters
            var params = train();

            // visualize model output
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            draw_grid();
            draw_points();
            visualize_params(params);

            // label what the model would say for a given mouse position
            window.onmousemove = function(evt) {
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 100, 50);

                let p = {x: 10, y: 20};

                let mouse = {x: evt.offsetX, y: evt.offsetY};
                let mouse_graph = to_graph(mouse.x, mouse.y);

                ctx.fillText("x: " + Math.round(mouse_graph.x*100)/100, p.x, p.y);
                ctx.fillText("y: " + Math.round(mouse_graph.y*100)/100, p.x, p.y +10);
                // model output
                let model_out = sigmoid( mouse_graph.x * params.w1 + mouse_graph.y * params.w2 + params.b );
                model_out = Math.round(model_out*100)/100;
                ctx.fillText("prediction: " + model_out, p.x, p.y + 20);
            }        
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Accept the answer if you are satisfied